# Chromecast H.264 transport stream

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast, transport-stream

I have seen a few times (here and on google cast issues) that Chromecast supports MPEG2-TS. May anybody give some closer information?

Also, when i try to reproduce .ts file which holds stream encoded with H.264, i get LOAD_METADATA_ERROR. 
Video is H.264/AAC,and samples are provided on github (sample_media_receiver.html and CastVideos-android).

The same thing happens when i try to reproduce m2ts files from here http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/cast-media-server-samples/media.zip.

//update #01
I use .ts file with 2 tracks:
File has 2 tracks
    Track 256 type: Video (H264) - Program 1
    Track 257 type: Audio (MP4A) - lang  und - Program 1

Could anybody provide me a **working** example URL ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found this url which works :

http://frlive.artestras.cshls.lldns.net/artestras/contrib/frlive.m3u8

I won't delete this post, maybe someone could find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Chromecast supports playing MPEG2-TS using [Media Source Extensions](http://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/).  The [default receiver](https://devsite.googleplex.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps#default) has only recently been extended to play unencrypted streaming media. (HLS, SmoothStreaming, and some forms of MPEG-Dash)

Comment: I am able to play HLS which consists of multiple .ts files. However, i am unable to play .ts files by providing the receiver with URL (<ip>/test.ts). I always get LOAD METADATA ERROR. Is this supported? In supported media, i can see only mp4 and WebM containers. That is quite strange; .ts as segment is valid, but alone is invalid.

Comment: I recall getting some .ts files to play with <video src='xxx.ts' />, but not all.  Not sure what the difference was. Generally I don't try.  Using MSE (above) to set the TS is the preferred way.